# how to add or edit gravitar within laravel

Tags: laravel, updates, gravatar

I know that we can user the gravitar in laravel for display pic but how can we add one if the new user doesn't have it or wish to update the current one from within the application?

below article shows how to show existing gravitar in laravel.

[How do I implement Gravatar in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724887/how-do-i-implement-gravatar-in-laravel)

Comment: You're gonna have to use the Gravatar API for that

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a default image through the Gravatar URL.

[Documentation](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/).